# sequential list for python poker program

Tags: python, class, set, poker

I want to build a straight function for a Texas hold'em program. I've created some test values  and want the function to return the list of cards that satisfy the straight.

This is what I have so far:

```
import cards

c1=cards.Card(1,1)
c2=cards.Card(2,1)
c3=cards.Card(3,2)
c4=cards.Card(4,2)
c5=cards.Card(5,2)
c6=cards.Card(6,4)
c7=cards.Card(3,4)
c8=cards.Card(7,3)
H1=[c7,c3,c2,c6,c5,c4,c1]
H2=[c1,c2,c3,c2,c3,c3,c8]


def build_rank_D(H):
    dict1={}
    for item in H:
        A=item.get_rank()
        if A not in dict1:
            dict1[A]=[item]


        else:
            dict1[A].append(item)





 return dict1

def straight(H):
    sequence=set()
    for item in H:
        A=item.get_rank()
        sequence.add(A)

    list_seq=list(sequence)
    n=list_seq[0]
    new_list=[]
    if list_seq[1]==n+1 and list_seq[2]==n+2 and list_seq[3]==n+3 and list_seq[4]==n+4
        print("you have a straight")
        return H

    else:
        print("no straight found")
    return []


print(straight(H1))

straight(H2)
```

Right now the function prints the entire set of cards, not the cards that satisfy the straight, which is what I want.

This is a sample of the cards class program that I've imported:

```
import random    # required for shuffle method of Deck

class Card(object):
    ''' Suit and rank are ints, and index into suit_list and rank_list.
        Value is different from rank: for example face cards are equal in value (all 10)
    '''
    # Use these lists to map the ints of suit and rank to nice words.
    # The 'x' is a place holder so that index-2 maps to '2', etc.
    suit_list = ['x','c','d','h','s']
    rank_list = ['x', 'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10','J', 'Q', 'K']

    def __init__(self, rank=0, suit=0):
        ''' Rank and suit must be ints. This checks that they are in the correct range.
            Blank card has rank and suit set to 0.
        '''
        if type(suit) == int and type(rank) == int:
            # only good indicies work
            if suit in range(1,5) and rank in range(1,15):
                self.__suit = suit
                self.__rank = rank

            else:
                self.__suit = 0
                self.__rank = 0
        else:
            self.__suit = 0
            self.__rank = 0
    def get_rank(self):
        return self.__rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.__suit
```

Comment: what about `return list_seq[0:5]` instead of `return H` ?

Comment: that would only return the ranks of the cards, not the cards themselves, which don't support indexing

Comment: in for loop, `rank` is not defined

Comment: fixed, but still no luck

Comment: can you write what will be the desired output for `print(straight(H1))`?

Comment: When I run it it prints [3s, 3d, 2c, 6s, 5d, 4d, Ac]. The correct output is supposed to be in any order [Ac, 2c, either 3s or 3d, 4d, 5d, 6s]

Answer (score 0):

What this does:

```
sequence = set()
...
list_seq=list(sequence)
```

is produce a list of integers in random order (set is unordered), you will want to sort the list first before making the comparisons.

Comment: I am still unable to print out only the cards that form a straight. My current function prints the entire list of cards. I am assuming I have to write a loop and iterate, but I'm not exactly sure. When I print out list_seq, the integers are in the correct order.

Comment: @user3477408: don't trust what you see when you print; integers are its own hash, which is why it will in many cases look like it's in order, but you'll get bitten when this accident of implementation doesn't hold. (e.g. `print list(set([1, 5, 11]))` produces `[1, 11, 5]`)

Answer (score 0):

As @LieRyan stated, first you have to be sure your cards are ordered, and then you can continue finding the straight.

For that, you can add a `__lt__(self, other)` method to your Card class that will allow you to order a list of class. In this method you order according to the rank:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.__rank < other.__rank:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then, to achieve the output you want I will recomend to add a `__repr__(self)` method to control how your Cards are printed:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.rank_list[self.__rank]) + str(self.suit_list[self.__suit])
```

Finally in your `stright(H)` you only need to order the Cards, get a list with unique ranks (I'm using a list `mycards` to control which cards are the *unique* one I'm considering), check your straight and print the 5 first cards from `mycards`:

```
def straight(H):
    H.sort()
    list_seq=[]
    mycards = []
    for item in H:
        A=item.get_rank()
        if A not in list_seq:
            list_seq.append(A)
            mycards.append(item)

    n=list_seq[0]
    new_list=[]
    if list_seq[1]==n+1 and list_seq[2]==n+2 and list_seq[3]==n+3 and list_seq[4]==n+4:
        print("you have a straight")
        return mycards[0:5]

    else:
        print("no straight found")
        return []
```

For `straight(H1)`, in my case, I'm getting:

```
you have a straight
[Ac, 2c, 3s, 4d, 5d]
```

If you want to print whole `H`, just omit the list `mycards` and print `H` (which is already ordered)

Comment: You didn't account for a case like [Q K A 2 3]